# How to link to a slide and skip all its animations?

Tags: keynote

In Keynote, I have 10 slides. On slide 3, I have a bunch of animations (i.e. I have to click 4 times until all the animations are done).

On slide 5, I have a button where clicking it will link back to slide 3. It works properly. The only problem is that it links to slide 3 before all the animations took place. I want it to link to slide 3 after all the animations happened.

Cause right now when I'm on slide 5, I click the button to go back to slide 3, and then have to click 4 times to get all the animations on slide 3 to play. That's a lot of clicking.

Is there a way to link to a slide's end state rather than its beginning state?

Answer (score 0):

To skip all the animation of a particular slide and go to the final stage, you can go to that slide, then do the following:

- press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>
- and then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: The question is about having a link to directly jump to the end of the slide animations, not about skiping them manually.